# how can i transfer input data in form with value using GET method

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I have a form and it has an input in it. I normally auto-fill this with javascript, but I didn't add this code because I know the problem is not in javascript. My main problem is that I fill the input using the value from the input and I have to give the input a disabled property. Here is the code:

```
<form action="testget.php" method="GET">
  <input disabled type="text" name="testget" value="testvalue">
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

When I press the send button, the url it will redirect me to should be:

```
localhost/testget.php?testget=testvalue
```

but here is the problem. The url it redirected me to:

```
localhost/testget.php?
```

I don't know if I misunderstood the value property, but how I tried to search on the internet, I could not find a solution for it. I will be glad if you help me.

I was trying and expecting for the data in the form to be transferred to testget.php.

Comment: Disabled elements won't get submitted with the form

Comment: "_and I have to give the input a disabled property_" Why is that? As said, disabled elements won't be submitted. You could use the `readonly` attribute instead so the user can not edit the control

Comment: it works! coincided with my inexperience :( Thanks for everything @brombeer

Comment: 1. you cannot prevent any value from being changed, no matter what. 2. Why you're sending it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to make the `disabled` part to `readonly` in your code